# can I use pushViewController:animated: in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sms

the example code of MFMessageComposeViewController uses presentModalViewController to change view into "new message compose view"

But I want to use pushViewController to push MFMessageComposeViewController into the stack, I've tried [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES],and [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker], both don't work.

how could I do that? thx

Comment: Show us some code. "both don't work." is not good enough. First guess (from your limited information) would be that your view has no `navigationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) you can use it by only presenting.

Hope it helps.